# Python Pandas | Create a new column - aggregate functions based on row-specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

Here is the simplified context. I have several types of goods (Goods_ID 0001, 0002 and 0003) where Multiple shops (A, B, C) have different prices.

I need to add two additional columns, "MinPriceShop" and "MinPrice", that outputs the shop who offers the lowest price and its respective price.

Input df:

```
Goods_ID    ShopID  Price
0001        A       10
0001        B       12
0002        A       23
0002        B       22
0003        A       5
0003        B       6
0003        C       4.5
```

Desired Output df:

```
Goods_ID    ShopID  Price   MinPriceShop   MinPrice
0001        A       10      A              10
0001        B       12      A              10
0002        A       23      B              22
0002        B       22      B              22
0003        A       5       C              4.5
0003        B       6       C              4.5
0003        C       4.5     C              4.5
```

I am not sure how I can apply an aggregate function (min, max, sum) to a dataframe, but with "row-specific"/"dynamic" conditions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for dataframe with rows by minimal `Price` per groups, rename columns and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) to original with left join.

Alternative solution use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
d = {'ShopID':' MinPriceShop','Price':'MinPrice'}
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('Goods_ID')['Price'].idxmin()].rename(columns=d)
#alternative solution:
#df1 = df.sort_values(['Goods_ID','Price']).drop_duplicates('Goods_ID').rename(columns=d)

df = pd.merge(df, df1, on='Goods_ID', how='left')
print (df)
   Goods_ID ShopID  Price  MinPriceShop  MinPrice
0         1      A   10.0             A      10.0
1         1      B   12.0             A      10.0
2         2      A   23.0             B      22.0
3         2      B   22.0             B      22.0
4         3      A    5.0             C       4.5
5         3      B    6.0             C       4.5
6         3      C    4.5             C       4.5
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df1)
   Goods_ID  MinPriceShop  MinPrice
0         1             A      10.0
3         2             B      22.0
6         3             C       4.5
```

Comment: Thanks the calculation works! Have never thought of creating a new df and merge with existing!